# Data update in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postman

I use React in my application. The user can update the data in his profile, but he is not required to specify all the fields, but can only choose one. Then I send "state", but if the user has filled only 1 field, then all the others are written as empty lines. I have already tried to do a check using the ternary operator, but this did not solve the problem. The server is working correctly when I update the data through "Postman", the rest is saved. How do I transfer data correctly?

```
state = {
    user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")),
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    gender: '',
    location: '',
    createdAt: '',
    updatedAt: ''
};

componentWillMount() {
    getUserById(this.state.user.id)
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                email: res.data.email,
                firstName: res.data.firstName,
                lastName: res.data.lastName,
                gender: res.data.gender,
                location: res.data.location,
                createdAt: res.data.createdAt,
                updatedAt: res.data.updatedAt
            })
        })
}

                this.setState({
                firstName: '' ? this.state.firstName : this.firstName,
                lastName: '',
                gender: '',
                location: '',
                });
```

Comment: can you add whole component code for more clearity

Comment: Why don't you set default values to the state?

Comment: I am not sure but it sounds like this is not a problem of react.
Is the state empty in the not updated fields? Try setting a value for each field, that. If the user changes it, it will override, of he hasn't changed it will be "changed" to the same as before.

Comment: Which data goes in?

Comment: The data comes from the server and is the default data.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: For example, the user previously indicated his last name, and later indicated his first name, and when he sends the name to the server, his last name is not overwritten, with an empty value.

Comment: Isn’t this in charge of your api? How it processes empty strings? I don’t see any line where the user sends his/her name btw.